# Querying a MySQL table with a JSON field and accessing JSON attributes

Tags: mysql, json

With MySQL 5.7 new features involving JSON has emerged. Among these features is the ability to query the fields in the JSON object as it is stored in the database.

My object looks like this.

```
{
"color": [
  {"WHITE" :{ "size": [
        {"S": [{"Price" : "31"},
              {"discountPrice" : "13" }]}
        ]}},
    {"BLACK" :{ "size": [
        {"S": "69"}, 
        {"M": "31"}, 
        {"L": "55.666"}
        ]}}
]}
```

I want to query this as if it was regular tabular data, to this end I tried the following query to no avail.

```
select json_extract(Sku, '$.color[0]') from CRAWL.DAILYDATA;
```

I want to explode this into a format that looks more like a traditional RDBMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have two questions here: Please elaborate a bit on `to no avail` and the `traditional RDBMS` result you are aiming for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get data out of a json object as values, you need to get all the way down to the values. For instance, if you wanted to pull all of the values like they are regular RDBMS columns:

```
select json_extract(Sku, '$.color[0].WHITE.size[0].S[0].price') as price,
json_extract(Sku, '$.color[0].WHITE.size[0].S[0].discountPrice') as discountPrice
from CRAWL.DAILYDATA;
```

Of course, you need to know exactly what you're looking for in the object. This is the price of having a schema-less object like json. In principle, you could define a mysql function that would use combinations of

```
json_contains_path
```

and

```
json_extract
```

to make sure the path you are looking for exists, and otherwise it returns null. Personally though, if you want the RDBMS quality, why not just force it into a form where you can put the values directly into mysql tables? This is, of course, why RDBMS's exist. If you can't put it into such a form, you're going to be stuck with searching your json as above.

Comment: This actually convinced me to not use JSON objects for this purpose. I am on the fence about using an RDBMS but it is clear that doing something in-between is probably the worst choice here. thanks for the answer.

Comment: A non-pure SQL answer is to do what you're doing, and then use a programming language that more naturally deals with JSON objects. For instance, do your simple query that gets the object you want, and then json_decode in PHP. MySQL just isn't set up to deal with schema-less objects in a clean way. Filtering or sorting will still be a challenge.